# Convert co-occurrence dataframe to square matrix

Tags: r

Say I have this dataframe:

```
    d <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), B = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), C = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), E = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), F = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), G = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), H = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))



      A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
2     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
3     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
4     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
5     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
6     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
7     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

I wish to turn this into a square matrix of 8x8 (A:H x A:H). Each cell equal the total times that each two letters appear together.  For example, The cell [A,B] should have a value of 6 as the columns A and B both have a 1 in 6 out of the 7 rows.  The cell [B,A] has the same value.  The output should be:

I can do this in a loop like this:

```
mat <- matrix(NA,8,8)
for(i in 1:8) { 
  for(j in 1:8) {
    mat[i,j] <- sum(mat1[,i]==1 & mat1[,j]==1)
    mat[j,i] <- sum(mat1[,j]==1 & mat1[,i]==1)
  }}
diag(mat)<-0
rownames(mat)<-colnames(mat)<-LETTERS[1:8]
mat
```

Desired output:

```
  A B C D E F G H
A 0 6 1 0 0 0 0 3
B 6 0 1 0 0 0 0 3
C 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
D 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
E 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
H 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

But this is slow when doing very large matrices.  Is there  a way of doing this quicker ?

Comment: `m <- crossprod(as.matrix(d))`; `diag(m) <- 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described in words sounded like ordinary matrix multiplication forllowed by setting the diag to 0:

```
temp <- t(as.matrix(d)) %*% as.matrix(d)
diag(temp) <- 0


> temp
  A B C D E F G H
A 0 6 1 0 0 0 0 3
B 6 0 1 0 0 0 0 3
C 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
D 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
E 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
H 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The `tcrossprod` function is probably even faster, but either of these methods will surely out-perform your nested loop.

Comment: Did you mean the `crossprod` function?